# drawing great circle path with cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm supposed to draw a map using cartopy. The assignment is:

Use the orthographic projection, centered on Hamburg, and draw the great circle path between Hamburg and Tokyo

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = long_ham, central_latitude = lat_ham))
ax.coastlines()


long_ham, lat_ham = 9.993682, 53.551086
long_tok, lat_tok = 139.839478, 35.652832

plt.plot([long_ham, long_tok], [lat_ham, lat_tok],
         color='blue', linewidth=2, marker='o',
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic(),
         )

plt.text(long_ham , lat_ham , 'Hamburg',
         horizontalalignment='right',
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.text(long_tok , lat_tok , 'Tokyo',
         horizontalalignment='left',
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

# Save the plot by calling plt.savefig() BEFORE plt.show()
plt.savefig('great circle distance.pdf')
plt.savefig('great circle distance.png')

plt.show()
```

[image: this is the result]

Is there a way to show the whole globe instead of the close up that I'm currently getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `ax.set_global()` before `savefig()` and `plt.show()`.

[image: global]